# Taking key as Value from json response

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, key-value

JSON:

```
    {
      "json": {
        "response": {
          "servicetype": "1",
          "functiontype": "10011",
          "statuscode": "0",
          "statusmessage": "Success",
          "data": {
            "unassignedroles": [
              {"roleid":"1",
                "roleinformation": {
                  "QA": [
                    {
                      "White Box Testing": 0
                    },
                    {
                     "Black Box Testing": 10
                    }

                  ]
                }
              },
              {
`              "roleid":"2"`,
                "roleinformation": {
                  "1": [
                    {
                      "A": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              { 
                "roleid":"3",
                "roleinformation": {
                  "D": [
                    {
                      "B": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I  need to pass my key as a value in my table . I stored my `$scope.roleInfo = response.json.data.unassignedRoles[i].roleinformation;`

Now from that `$scope.roleInfo` for instance ,I have

```
QA  [
            {
              "White Box Testing": 0
            },
            {
             "Black Box Testing": 10
            }

          ]
```

How to give Key QA , White Box Testing and Black Box testing in table dynamically based on the roleid selected. For each role id I will have different key name.

Comment: Do you want to display these in a table?

Comment: Yes , I want to display them in table.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `roleInformation` sub-object (thus the `$scope.roleInfo` object) has only one key, so if you do:

```
for (i in $scope.roleInfo)
    console.log(i) // i == "QA"
```

the "loop" will only run once and you can extract the desired value.

So just the same way, you can

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in roleInfo">
    <td>{{ key }}</td>

    <td ng-repeat="details in value">
        <p ng-repeat"(subkey, subvalue) in details">{{ subkey }} : {{ subvalue }}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your assistance , but it works for only one key it replace the other key , if I have two value and moreover this html code is not working.I tried it in sameway.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your JSON to scope object and iterate it in for each as below.

angular.forEach($scopeObject, function(value, Key) {
}

You will get the "Key" while iteration happen.
By this way you can filter the "key" from JSON list.

Comment: could you please give me any example. i am kind of new to this.